LTSpice-MOSFET switching problem
Why is this happening in LTSpice? Is my circuit wrong?



Because you are using the active load (Current source) I1 in reverse so the current flows from the ground (not exiting the voltage source + node), through the NMOS body diode (see the red diode below) to the voltage source V7's (+) node. I marked the flow direction with green below:

If you put the I1 the other way round (upside down) you'll see the voltage at Power_Out node goes negative.
You can use load2 instead which has an arrow on it to show the current flow direction, so it's less confusing.


If the current source is used to model a dissipative load, then it’s also a good idea to check the box in the Advanced options that says This is an active load.

Why do you think anything is wrong? The load "I1" is just a variable resistor set to a fixed value of 3Ω, in spite of being labeled "I1". What do you expect to be happening?
The simulation is not useful anyway, because the built-in NMOS and PMOS models are representative of devices you'd find on a chip, not of discrete mosfets. You need to choose an actual real-world part number and corresponding model for the mosfet.
The simulation isn't set up to catch exceeding the gate-source absolute voltage limit. If you assembled this circuit in the real world, the mosfet would be destroyed, since the gate-source voltage is -48V. Usually it can't be more than say -20V.
The control voltage for the mosfet needs to be applied between the source and the gate, and it must be limited to say -15V..-20V. E.g. if you were using 9V batteries:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The IRF9Z34 allows ±20V maximum gate-source voltage as the absolute limit. 18V from two 9V batteries in series would be OK.
In a practical circuit, C1 is needed to avoid exceeding the gate-source maximum voltage due to slewing (changing voltage) on the drain when the mosfet turns on. There is plenty of capacitive coupling between the drain and gate, and the 9V batteries have internal resistance much higher than the AC resistance of this mosfet's gate. Thus C1 shunts the AC current when M1 turns on and its drain swings from around 0V to +48V. When the mosfet is turning off, the switch itself shunts this current.
C1 and the switch need to be connected to the mosfet with very short wires - less than 1 inch total length, ideally. This is to maintain reasonably fast switching times, to avoid overheating the mosfet due to channel conductive loss during the switching transient.

The load "I1" is just a variable resistor set to a fixed value of 3Ω. No, it acts as a current source. See my answer.

Let's say LTSpice got an interesting choice for a symbol then... unnecessarily misleading.

Load I1 looks like a variable resistor but it is indeed a current source. Certainly a very odd symbol for that source.  I always use the symbol  with a circle and an arrow inside to show the direction of the current flow.

Yeah, it's a terrible symbol.  Prefix field should default to R instead of I.  It's been like that for so long, though, that if they change it now it would break any old schematic that uses it.
